# What is the concept of "third" in Primitive function scheme?

Tags: scheme, primitive

I am new at scheme computation.

I have a given problem:

(DEFINE (third C) (CAR(CDR CDR(C))))

(third ‘(A (B C) (D E) F))

I know the concept of CDR and CAR, but I don't understand what will "third" do. I read that it is a way to define "threesome???".

I am inclined to replace the value of C by the value of the second statement next to third which is ‘(A (B C) (D E) F), is this correct?

Can you explain in simple term as possible what "third" do in this given and how can I solve this given problem?

Comment: Um, it returns the third element of the list... did you not try it and see?

Comment: Though that implementation of `third` is not valid, the ones that come built into scheme implementations like racket or in libraries like SRFI-1 will work. It's just an alias for `caddr` that's easier to read.

Comment: Do we have a solver for this? It is one of the topics in my MS study. Our professor just thought us about the theory and how CDR and CAR and CONS work.  Where can I test this?

Comment: Download any Scheme interpreter and try it yourself (Racket, for example). How are you going to learn just by reading the theory? get to write some code, test it, see it running!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lisps the list is a fundamental data structure, and it is comprised of pairs. Traditionally, the first member of the pair is called its *car*, and the second member is called its *cdr*:

> ( car . cdr )

Here the dot indicates that the pair is composed of two cells. Given a pair, `(a . b)`, the accessor for the first member is also called `car`, and the accessor for the second member is called `cdr`. So:

> `(car '(a . b))` --> `a`, and
> `(cdr '(a . b))` --> `b`.

To form a list, pairs are combined in the following way: the first member of the first pair is the first element of the list, and the second member of the first pair is either the empty list or a pair representing the rest of the list. So, a list of one element, e.g., `(a)` is represented by the pair `(a . ())`.

A list of two elements, e.g., `(a b)` is represented by the pair `(a . (b . ()))`. Here, the second member of the first pair is the pair `(b . ())`. You will note that the `cdr` of the list `(a b)` is the list `(b)`, or equivalently `(b . ())`.

A list of three elements, e.g., `(a b c)` is similarly represented as `(a . (b . (c . ())))`. A list is a pair which has either the empty list `()` or a pair in its `cdr`. There is a distinction to be made here about proper lists (the final pair must have a `()` in its `cdr`) and improper lists, but I will ignore that distinction here. And the empty list is also a list (but not a pair). To make things a bit more precise: in Scheme a list is either the empty list or a pair whose cdr is a list.

So, `car` gets the first member of a list, and `cdr` gets the rest of the list. Given the list `(a b c d)` we can see that:

> `(cdr '(a b c d))` --> `(b c d)`, and
> `(cdr (cdr '(a b c d)))` --> `(cdr '(b c d))` --> `(c d)`, and
> `(car (cdr (cdr '(a b c d))))` --> `(car (cdr '(b c d)))` --> `(car '(c d))` --> `c`.

So, given the definition:

```scheme
(define (third xs)
  (car (cdr (cdr xs))))
```

We have:

```
> (third '(a b c d))
c
```

I will leave it to the OP to apply this information to the question of:

> `(third '(a (b c) (d e) f))` --> **?**

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I wonder if the QUOTE ' is important like for the given `(DEFINE (third C) (CAR(CDR CDR(C))))`, my professor didn't give the value of C. So, we are assuming the value is just C.  

Can i say that cdr(C) = cdr(C. ()) even without the QUOTE '

Comment: @GieGrajo -- the quote is not part of the list; it is shorthand for `quote`, which is not a function but usually called a _special form_. Function calls are indicated with parentheses in lisps, so `(third '(a b c))` says to call the function `third` with the argument `(a b c)`. But, functions _always_ evaluate their arguments in lisps, so `(third (a b c))` without the quote attempts to evaluate `(a b c)`, which is a _function call_ that tries to call  the function `a` with arguments `b` and `c`. The quote _suppresses evaluation_....

Comment: So, `'(a b c)` evaluates to the list `(a b c)`, but `(a b c)` evaluates to a function call. As I said, the single quote is a shorthand for `quote`, so you can also do `(quote (a b c))`, which evaluates to the list `(a b c)`, i.e., `(third (quote (a b c)))`.

Comment: Now, you have `cdr(C)` = `cdr(C . ())`, and also `(CAR (CDR CDR(C)))`. The parentheses are out of place here; remember that parentheses indicate function calls in lisps (except for some special cases). You need `(cdr C)` to get the cdr of `C`. But `(cdr '(C . ()))` is `()`, so not =. And, you need `(CAR (CDR (CDR C)))` instead of `(CAR (CDR CDR(C)))`.

Comment: But, in the function definition you do not want to quote `C`, because it is a _parameter_ to the function which will be filled in by an _argument_ when the function is called. Note that I used `xs` instead of `C` in the definition for `third` in my answer. No particular reason, except that I usually use `xs` for generic lists (which contain a bunch of elements `x`).